# Do Multi-Primary replicated distributed systems guarantee sequential consistency?

Tags: distributed-system

I know that Primary-backup replicated distributed systems guarantee sequential consistency.
My question is whether multi-primary systems also achieve that.

I mean if they use consensus (i.e: Paxos algorithm) to agree on an order for the received requests, then I suppose sequential consistency is achieved.
But if they just use conflict-free replicated data types, would that achieve sequential consistency?